# Include JMockit Coverage in Sonarqube dashboard

Tags: java, code-coverage, sonarqube, jmockit

I'm looking for a way to include the JMockit-Coverage reports of my multi-module java project 
into our SonarQube managing this project. We already have the Cobertura reports in Sonar, but I'd like to have both available easily to be able to compare them.

The JMockit doc talks about something to generate a coverage.ser file, I didn't go there as I'm not sure this file would be usefull to Sonar or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to include the .ser file to the sonar export.

BUT you can add the Jacoco dependency that will use the JMockit coverage to generate a report that sonar will use.

```
    <profile>
        <id>coverage</id>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmockit-coverage</artifactId>
                <version>${jmockit.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <coverage-classes>com.mypackage.*</coverage-classes>
                            <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

I think that your cobertura report will also include coverage from the jmockit coverage.

Comment: sorry I don't work on this project any more, so without the sources, it is difficult to validate your solution (and I'd rather not recreate this kind of conf just for the pleasure ;) )